# A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in glib-sharp.dll

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gtk#

I am trying to  debug and   this error comes up everytime and stops executing. I have all my references copied into the debug folder and still the error remains I need to know how can I reference the `glib-sharp.dll` which is in  my debug  folder. my error output is :

```
  'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Symbols loaded.
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\web4\bin\x86\Debug\WebMobility.vshost.exe'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Red Gate\.NET Reflector\DevPath\gtk-sharp.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Red Gate\.NET Reflector\DevPath\gdk-sharp.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Red Gate\.NET Reflector\DevPath\pango-sharp.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Red Gate\.NET Reflector\DevPath\glib-sharp.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Red Gate\.NET Reflector\DevPath\Mono.Posix.dll'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
    The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1a5c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x1a48) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x1584) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0xbf8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\web4\bin\x86\Debug\WebMobility.exe'
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Red Gate\.NET Reflector\DevPath\WMLibrary.dll', Symbols loaded.
    'WebMobility.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Red Gate\.NET Reflector\DevPath\atk-sharp.dll'
    Starting WMeXplore
    A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in glib-sharp.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in WebMobility.exe
    System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gtk.Application' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'glibsharpglue-2': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
       at GLib.Thread.glibsharp_g_thread_supported()
       at GLib.Thread.get_Supported()
       at Gtk.Application..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Gtk.Application.Init()
       at WMeXplore.MainClass.Main(String[] args)
    The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x1f44) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x9c4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The program '[7716] WebMobility.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

second error after installing

```
private enum CameraEnum //   errror  identifier excepted public is keyword.     {
        {
            public const GtkController<T>.CameraEnum Camsat = GtkController<T>.CameraEnum.Camsat;,identifier e3xcepted
            public const GtkController<T>.CameraEnum Docking = GtkController<T>.CameraEnum.Docking;,//errro :invalid token',' in class,struct, or interface member declaration//
            public const GtkController<T>.CameraEnum Internal = GtkController<T>.CameraEnum.Internal;
        }

        public delegate void TaskFunction();
    }
} //Error type or namespace definition, or end of file excepted.//
```